# Breaking a string up into multiple strings on a certain symbol

Tags: c#, .net, string

If I have a string that I know will be formatted like this:

```
string teststring = "test1;#test2;#test3;#";
```

and I wanted to automatically turn this into:

```
string string1 = "test1";
string string2 = "test2";
string string3 = "test3";
```

what would be the best way to set this up?

Comment: Have you looked into the [Split() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

```
string[] parts = teststring.Split(
    new string[] { ";#" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Won't that result in an array like `test1, #test2, #test3` etc...?

Comment: this only answers half the question I believe. Now how does he set string string1 = "test1";?

Comment: @user2140261 There should be no need for the `string1`-`stringN` variables, since `parts` contains all parts of the original string (`parts[0] == "test1"`, `parts[1] == "test2"`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Use string Split:

```
sting[] myStrings = teststring.Split(new string[] {";#"}, , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string piece in myStrings)
{
    //Do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know how long the string will be? It could be just one part or many sections.

Comment: Take a look at my update if you want to do something with every piece of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into an array based on the ';#' characters.

```
string[] parts = teststring.Split(";#")
parts[0]; // string1.  
parts[1]; // string2.  
parts[2]; // string3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into an array:

```
string[] = teststring.Split("#");
```

Comment: I think you mean `teststring.Split(";#");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = teststring.Split(new String[]){";#"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Altering code from MSDN found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

```
using System;

public class SplitTest {
public static void Main() {

    string teststring = "test1;#test2;#test3;#";

    string [] split = teststring.Split(new Char []{';','#'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var SplitStringList = new Dictionary<String, String>();


    for (int i=0;i<split.Length;i++)
    {

        if (split[i].Trim() != "")
        {
            SplitStringList.Add("string"+1, split[i]);
        }


    }
  }
}
```

Now you can get the string-value of a given string-key in this way:

```
String Anything = SplitStringList["string1"];
```

The example adds the following strings to the Dictionary SplitStringList: 
    Key:string1 Value: test1
    Key:string2 Value: test2
    Key:string3 Value: test3

With matching keys so that you can then use these strings in more depth throughout the rest of your code. Just reference the key.

Comment: You don't need `if (split[i].Trim() != "")` since you're using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` Also, your `SplitStringList` can be populated by passing the array of strings in the constructor saving even more lines of code.

Comment: Just wanted to show him extra ways he could work with the resulting array.